# Jquery Timers - Cant stop everyTime loop

Tags: jquery, timer, jquery-animate

I have a little animation that makes elements bob up and down.  Each element bobs at a slightly different speed and amount.
I'm using Jquery Timers (http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers) everyTime function to infinitely loop the animation.

I've successfully got the elements to bob up and down, but I can't get them to stop using the stopTime() function.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function randomFromTo(from, to){
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

    function bobbing(command){

       if(command=='start'){
          $("#scroller .feature-headline").each(function (i) {
             $(this).everyTime(1, 'bobbing', function (){
                var bobAmount = randomFromTo(5, 10);
                var bobSpeed = randomFromTo(1200, 2000);
                $(this).animate ({marginTop: bobAmount}, bobSpeed, 'linear').animate ({marginTop: 0}, bobSpeed, 'linear');
             });
          });
       } else {
          $("#scroller .feature-headline").each(function (i) {
             $(this).stopTime('bobbing');
          });
       }

    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.irengba.com/codewell/) makes a distinction between stopping the timer and stopping the animation. It's example to completely stop the animation is

```
$( "#ball_holder").stop(true).stopTime();
```

...so I would try

```
$(this).stop(true).stopTime('bobbing');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mqsoh.  The animation carries on unfortunately.  It may stop for a second, but its hard to tell.  The animation itself is very jerky so I wonder if I need to approach the whole thing in a different way... just not sure how!

Comment: I noticed that your bobbing function is indented more than the random number function. It may help to include other parts of your code; have you checked that you're not starting the animation in a loop?

Comment: I'll try and knock up a demo as the full code is work in progress i.e. very messy! LOL.  Be right back.

Comment: Hmmmmm.  In the stripped out demo I've being making, everything works perfectly so I need to have a good look through the original code and see what's different.  I might be something to do with having the elements within a carousel.

Comment: Firefox crashed on me then when it restarted everything was working as expected!  I wonder if it was a caching thing?  Anyway, thank you mqsoh, your suggestion worked perfectly :)